# don't know why: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, group-by

I want to improve my previous cod so that the three Pies can be drawn at once.

> `<class 'str'>`
> data = a.groupby(i)['income'].sum()
> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'groupby'

the data is like this:

```
ta  tb    tc  ...   income
1   2011   a  ...   1352.23
1   2012   c  ...   706.87
2   2011   b  ...   3618.04
2   2012   c  ...   11745.42
3   2013   a  ...   345.98
```

What i want like this:

```py
    df = pd.read_csv('e:/test_csv', low_memory=False)
    a = ['ta', 'tb', 'tc']
    for i in a:
        print(type(i))
        data = df.groupby(i)['income'].sum()
        data.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')
    plt.show()
```

The previous CODE: *But somehow got the AttributeError*

```
df = pd.read_csv('e:/test_csv', low_memory=False)

data1 = a.groupby('ta')['income'].sum()
data1.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')

data2 = a.groupby('tb')['income'].sum()
data2.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')

data3 = a.groupby('tc')['income'].sum()
data3.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')

plt.show()
```

Comment: it's `a` that doesn't have the attribute `groupby`. What did you expect `a` to be?

Comment: `groupby` is a method of a `dataframe` not `list`. And `a` is a list. Hence, it throws the error. You should change it to: `data = df.groupby(i)['income'].sum()`

Comment: @thx Adam Smith. I want to draw 3 `pie chart` with less code, I added the details at the end of the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `df.groupby(i)` with `plt.figure()` for 3 separately pie graphs:

```
a = ['ta', 'tb', 'tc']
for i in a:
    d = df.groupby(i)['income'].sum()
    plt.figure()
    d.plot.pie(autopct='%.1f%%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your `for` loop and do this instead:

```
data = df.groupby(['ta', 'tb', 'tc'])['income'].sum()
```

Then plot it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct usage of groupby in pandas is this:

```
data.groupby(['col1', 'col2'])['col3'].sum()
```

You should have had:

```
data = df.groupby(['ta', 'tb', 'tc'])['income'].sum()
```

[Official Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to refer.